# infinite recursion in google app engine logging system

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, recursion

On my local instance of the app engine application I am developing I am experiencing an infinite recursion of the logging system. Unfortunately, since the problem lies in the logging system, I cannot see the error message. The python 'print' command is also not working on a google app engine application, therefore I cannot display any useful information.

The problem is visible even just accessing the website root.

It seems to be an import problem, but beside that, the logging system should work, and it doesn't.

The deployed version of the site is working, which leads me to think about a possible local configuration/system problem.

I am using python 2.7.2 and CURRENT_VERSION_ID=1.1

Here is the very long stacktrace of the bug:

```
    --> --> -->
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2781, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2669, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 692, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1731, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1631, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(config, handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1319, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\admin\__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp import _template
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\_template.py", line 37, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\template.py", line 61, in <module>
    webapp._config_handle.django_setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 153, in _django_setup
    __django_version_setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 99, in __django_version_setup
    'http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/'
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1582, in warning
    root.warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1144, in warning
    self._log(WARNING, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 870, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 797, in handleError
    None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1492, in write
    logging.getLogger()._log(logging.ERROR, message, ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1249, in _log
    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1223, in makeRecord
    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 266, in __init__
    self.levelname = getLevelName(level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 167, in getLevelName
    return _levelNames.get(level, ("Level %s" % level))
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

Here is the list of imports of main.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

import fix_path
import sys
import os
import urllib
import urllib2
import pprint
import logging
import cgi
import random
import Cookie
import datetime
import time
import urlparse
import urllib2
import urllib, cStringIO
import hashlib
import copy

from urllib import urlretrieve
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from django.utils import simplejson
from gaesessions import get_current_session

from myapp.models import *
from myapp.models import sequence_selection as models_sequence_selection
from myapp.sequence_selection import utils as sequence_selection_utils
from myapp.models import video 
from myapp.models.video import * 
from myapp.models.song import * 
from myapp.models.flashified import *
from myapp.music_recommendation import get_song_recommendations,get_song_recommendations_learning_data,learn_song,learn_song_from_video

from myapp.core import is_number
from myapp import mailing
from myapp import search
from myapp import motif
from myapp import retrieve_instagram
from myapp import coords_distance
from myapp import performancetest

from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.api import images
```

Actually, renaming the directory of the application and re-importing trough google app engine launcher with a different port solved my problem, but probably not the bug.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post an excerpt of your code?

Comment: actually, the main.py is a huge file with thousands of lines. I am also not sure that it is the source of the problem, since the recursion is made in the logging module. It also seems that my recent changes are unrelated to the bug, since I have undone them and the bug is still there.

Comment: At least the traceback you posted indicates that the problem originates when you import your modules (from myapp.music_recommendation import get_song_recommendations,get_song_recommendations_learning_data,learn_song,learn_song_from_video and from myapp.models.song import Song). Also what python version and dev_appserver are you using?

Comment: You could use the `logger.info('Some debug info')` to debug anything.. and see the result in the log output, instead of print. Don't use print in GAE

Comment: Hi Lipis, I actually use logger.info but the bug seems to be inside the logging system, therefore I had to experiment with print. And it didn't work.

Comment: @skreft: I have moved those imports to see if the bug was still there and it is still there. I have replaced the stacktrace. Now it is clear that the problem seems to be originating from google app-engine or some issues related to the OS or configuration, maybe? I don't know..

Comment: Actually, I have replaced the local application with a version slightly older, undoing the most recent changes. Now it works. I have looked in the changes from the old to the new version of the application, but could not find anything relevant. Therefore it must be something outside my code.

Comment: I have re-applied all the recent changes to the old code, and still the bug is not there.

Comment: It is an interesting problem. It seems somehow the logging code encounters an error and tries to log an error message.  This could well be a bug in the SDK, but it's hard to track down since you don't seem to have a simple reproducible case that I could try.  If this happens again I hope you will try to pare down your app to the smallest amount of code that still triggers the problem, and then file a bug in the App Engine tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload the relevant source to get a real answer as @skreft stated.

Although as far as logging, use `import logging` and then `logging.info()` to help locate the problem.

I suggest commenting the logging code for now and see what your stack trace reveals.  Then if you are not getting an error start adding the logging code back in piece by piece until you find your error.